# How to detect how much the view has scroll ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

How can i detect how much a scroll view has scrolled ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `onScrollChanged()` method of the ScrollView:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

    Log.i(TAG, "View onScrollChanged");
    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY()));// Calculate

    super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
}
```

Here, `diff` is the space left for scrolling between the bottom edge of the `ScrollView`, and the currently visible content at the bottom. When `diff = 0`, the `ScrollView` has been scrolled down fully.