# how much can a scrollView scroll?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, scroll, onmeasure

I have a layout with a scrollView inside it.

How can I calculate what's the possible scroll size?

I would think:

`(scroll's content desired height) - window.height = (invisible content height)`

But how do I get the scroll's content actual desired height?

I can get the scrollView height, which is not what I need.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12543514/311130), but I don't get the calaulation.

`int diff = (view.getBottom() - (getHeight() + getScrollY()));// Calculate`

Comment: Try this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609297/android-total-height-of-scrollview

Comment: @Elad Benda, why are you trying to calculate the scrollable height? Can you please specify the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can do it by the following two attributes in xml in scrollview it will scroll 
//accroding to the child views it contain
     android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
     android:orientation="vertical"

//here is the full example 
 <ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
 android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".fragments.frag1"
 >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bgsecond"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
     >
  </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```